# Error "you cannot call a method on a null-valued expression" when running script as scheduled task

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

This script runs fine in PowerShell. However, when I run it with Task Scheduler it fails with

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression on PowerShell script.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
$global:reports
$global:strdate
$global:ReportName
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=DWPROD;Database=DP_DW;Integrated Security=True"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = " Select
   email = 'user@example.com'
  ,username='example\user'
  ,password='password'
  ,ReportName = 'LaborAnalysis Kronos Daily'
  ,ReportFileName = 'LaborAnalysisDaily-'
  ,ReportDate = CONVERT(varchar,getdate()-2,101)
  ,Sharepoint = 'http://intranet.shccs.com/shcsites/toolbox/D  Labor/Daily Reports/'"
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$reportinfo = $DataSet.Tables[0]
$SqlConnection.Close()

#ARRAY TO SAVE Report Criteria
$a = 0
foreach ($reportparam in $reportinfo.Rows)
{
  $ReportName = $reportparam['ReportName']
  $ReportFileName = $reportparam['ReportFileName']
  $ReportDate = $reportparam['ReportDate']
  $Sharepoint = $reportparam['Sharepoint']

  #Write-Host $ReportName + $ReportDate
  Write-Host $ReportDate
  #Write-Host $Sharepoint
  #Write-Host (Get-date).AddDays(-1)
  #Write-Host $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd)
  #--------------------------------------------------------------
  # report parameters
  #--------------------------------------------------------------
  $inputParams = @{
    "prmRptDate" = '11/16/2016'
  }
  #--------------------------------------------------------------
  # add assembly
  #--------------------------------------------------------------
  Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"
  #Add-Type -AssemblyName -Path 'C:\Scripts\itextsharp.dll'
  #[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom('\\itextsharp.dll') | Out-Null
  #--------------------------------------------------------------
  # display calculated month end date
  #--------------------------------------------------------------
  $startTime = Get-Date
  Write-Host ("=" * 80)
  Write-Host "Generating Reports"
  Write-Host "Start Time: $startTime"
  Write-Host ("=" * 80)

  #--------------------------------------------------------------
  # create timestamped folder
  # where we will save our report
  #--------------------------------------------------------------
  $dt = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MMM-dd hhmmtt"
  $rptdt = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-mm-dd"
  $baseFolder = "C:Scripts"
  Remove-Item "C:\Scripts\Labor\*"

  $rv = New-Object Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer
  #--------------------------------------------------------------
  # report Server Properties
  #--------------------------------------------------------------
  $strdate = $ReportDate -replace "/", "-"
  $reports = $ReportFileName + $strdate + "pdf";

  $rv.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = "http://dpweb01.shccs.com/ReportServer"
  $rv.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Labor/"+ $ReportName
  $rv.ProcessingMode = "Remote"
  #Write-Host $ReportName
  #--------------------------------------------------------------
  # set up report parameters
  #--------------------------------------------------------------
  $params = $null

  #create an array based on how many incoming parameters
  $params = New-Object 'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter[]' $inputParams.Count

  $d = 0
  foreach ($p in $inputParams.GetEnumerator())
  {
    $params[$d] = New-Object Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter($p.Name, $p.Value, $false)
    $d++
  }
  # set the parameters
  $rv.ServerReport.SetParameters($params)
  $rv.ShowParameterPrompts = $false
  $rv.RefreshReport()
  $rv.ServerReport.Refresh()

  #--------------------------------------------------------------
  # set rendering parameters
  #--------------------------------------------------------------
  $mimeType = $null
  $encoding = $null
  $extension = $null
  $streamids = $null
  $warnings = $null

  #--------------------------------------------------------------
  # render the SSRS report in PDF
  #--------------------------------------------------------------
  $bytes = $null
  $bytes = $rv.ServerReport.Render("PDF",
           $null,
           [ref] $mimeType,
           [ref] $encoding,
           [ref] $extension,
           [ref] $streamids,
           [ref] $warnings)

  #--------------------------------------------------------------
  # save the report to a file
  #--------------------------------------------------------------
  $fileName = "C:/Scripts/Labor/" + $reports
  $fileStream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($fileName, [System.IO.FileMode]::OpenOrCreate)
  $fileStream.Write($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length)
  $fileStream.Close()
  $fileStream.Dispose();
  $reportdone = $reportname + " " + $(Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd) + ".PDF"
  #Write-Host $reportdone

  #--------------------------------------------------------------
  # Copy FIlES to Sharepoint
  #--------------------------------------------------------------
  # Set the variables
  $destination = "http://intranet.shccs.com/shcsites/toolbox/D  Labor/Daily Reports/"
  $File = Get-ChildItem "C:\Scripts\Labor"
  $FilePath = $File.FullName
  Write-Host $FilePath
  # Since we're doing this remotely, we need to authenticate
  $securePasssword = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
  $credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("example\user", $securePasssword)

  # Upload the file
  $webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
  $webclient.Credentials = $credentials
  $fileupload = $destination + $File
  Write-Host $fileupload
  $webclient.UploadFile($fileupload, "PUT", $FilePath)

  #$file = "c:\Scripts\file.txt"
  #$FilePath | Add-Content -Path $file
  #$fileupload | Add-Content -Path $file
  $a++
}
Send-MailMessage -To "user <user@example.com>" -From "user <user@example.com>" -Cc "user <user@example.com>" -Subject "Daily Labor Reports are Complete" -SmtpServer "relay.example.com" -Body "Labor Reports have been uploaded"

#--------------------------------------------------------------
# LOG ERROS
#--------------------------------------------------------------
$LaborLogs = "c:\Scripts\LaborLogs.txt"
#$error[0].Exception | gm

Add-Content $LaborLogs ("=" * 80)
Add-Content $LaborLogs $startTime
Add-Content $LaborLogs $strdate
Add-Content $LaborLogs $error[0]
Add-Content $LaborLogs ("=" * 80)
```

Comment: Is all the stuff at the top of your post outside of the code block part of the script or part of the error message?  either way can you show us how you are setting up the task scheduler job?

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say your SQL connection is failing to auth with the account that the scheduled task is running as, but without knowing how your scheduled task is configured its hard to tell.

Comment: I agree with @TheMadTechnician that how you configured the task to run and under what user is the source of your issue. You also have clear text password, emails and weblinks in you code you might want to remove.